# why is ERC721 ownerOf function referenced differently from all other function internally

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin

In the following function taken from Openzeppelin's ERC721 contract why is `ERC721.ownerOf()` called as if it were a static function while all others are referenced without referencing the contract itself (ex: `getApproved`)?  Is this just a convention? I can't find anything unusual in the function signature that would set it apart from other methods.

```
function _isApprovedOrOwner(address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
    require(_exists(tokenId), "ERC721: operator query for nonexistent token");
    address owner = ERC721.ownerOf(tokenId);
    return (spender == owner || getApproved(tokenId) == spender || isApprovedForAll(owner, spender));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ensures that the ownerOf function called is always the one defined in OpenZeppelin ERC721 implementation, even the ownerOf function is overridden in a child contract.

There is nothing unusual about the signature of the function, it's what it does that is critical: defining ownership relative to the actual storage state of the contract.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/issues/2784):

"The reason it's built this way is that it's otherwise impossible for us to assure internal consistency of our contract if ERC721.ownerOf can be anything other than the owner we have in storage. The burden of guaranteeing internal consistency is moved to the developer who wishes to override in these niche cases."

You can see that behaviour in the following example :

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

interface Interface {
    function ownerOf() external view returns (address);
}

contract Parent is Interface {
      
    function ownerOf() public view virtual override returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }
    
    function getOwnerOfSecure() public view returns (address) {
        return Parent.ownerOf();
    }
    
    function getOwnerOfInsecure() public view returns (address) {
        return ownerOf();
    }
}

contract Child is Parent {
    function ownerOf() public view virtual override returns (address) {
        return address(0);
    }
    
}
```

getOwnerOfSecure never changes behavior while getOwnerOfInsecure is changed when ownerOf is overridden by a child class.